# How can I collect the number of times a tag is used per month using the API?

Tags: support, tags, api

What is the best way to collect the number of times a given tag is used in a given month using the stack exchange API?

Is it by going through all the questions asked during a the given month that are tagged with the given tag?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the number of times a tag is used, merely fetch [the `/questions` route](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions), as follows:

1. Send the tag(s) in the `tagged` parameter.
2. Sort on `creation`.
3. Specify `fromdate` and `todate` to correspond to the month in question.
4. Use [the `total` filter](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/filters).

For example, for the `elasticsearch` tag, and the month of August 2017, you would use:

```
/questions?fromdate=1501545600&todate=1504224000&sort=creation&tagged=elasticsearch&filter=total
```

Here is [**a demo link for that**](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions#fromdate=2017-08-01&todate=2017-09-01&order=desc&sort=creation&tagged=elasticsearch&filter=total&site=stackoverflow&run=true).
It returns 850 questions for that tag for that month, which matches [the live website search with the same criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Belasticsearch%5D%20is%3Aquestion%20created%3A2017-08).

Note that depending on what you are really trying to do, the API may not be the best tool.
For more complicated queries, use [SEDE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/data-explorer/info).
[Here is an example, showing question growth](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/201360/question-count-or-score-growth-over-time-by-tag-comparison?ShowScore=0&Tag1=elasticsearch&Tag2=NA&Tag3=NA&Tag4=NA#graph).